# Converting utf-8 to latin-1 in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I want to do this:

Take the bytes of this utf-8 string:

访视频

Encode those bytes in latin-1 and print the result:

è®¿è§†é¢‘

How do I do this in Python?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
s = u'访视频'.encode('latin-1')
```

Causes this exception:

```
s = u'访视频'.encode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asking to do is literally impossible. You can't encode those characters to Latin-1, because those characters don't exist in Latin-1.

To get the output you want, you want to *decode* the UTF-8 bytes *as if they were Latin-1*. Like this:

```
s = u'访视频'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
```

However, your desired output doesn't look like actual Latin-1, because in Latin-1, characters `\x86` and `\x91` are non-printable, so you're going to get this:

```
è®¿è§ é¢
```

(Notice that space in the middle in place of `†`, and the missing `‘` at the end; those are actually invisible control characters, not spaces.)

It looks like you want a Latin-1 superset, probably Windows codepage 1252. In which case what you really want is:

```
s = u'访视频'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm on a Mac and I retrieved that string using an ISO-8559-1 encoding, but your second example is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @OregonTrail: A lot of websites, text files, etc. claim they're in ISO-8859-1 (not 8559, but I'm sure that was a meaningless typo) when they're actually in some extended version because the author doesn't know the difference. Especially Windows users, who think that their own OEM code page (usually cp1252) is Latin-1. (You also used to occasionally see the codepage Windows uses for remapping MacRoman to be sort of Latin-1-ish, which I forget the number of, but that was a long time ago.)

Comment: Any idea how to do the opposite? Take "è®¿è§†é¢‘" and get back "访视频". I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Ok, so `s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` obviously works in this example, but I'm running into a bigger problem in my actual codebase that I can't pin down.

Comment: @OregonTrail: As I explained in the answer, `\x86` and `\x91` are non-printable control characters, not `†` and `‘`, and nothing in Latin-1 is `†` or `‘`. So, of course `"è®¿è§†é¢‘".encode('latin-1')` is going to give you an exception. But if you use `encode('cp1252')`, as explained in the answer, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

you need to first encode to `UTF-8` (`UTF-8` can encode any Unicode string) and yet fully compatible with the `7-bit ASCII` set (**any ASCII bytestring is a correct `UTF-8–encoded` string**). :

```
>>> u'访视频'.encode('UTF-8').decode('latin-1')
u'\xe8\xae\xbf\xe8\xa7\x86\xe9\xa2\x91'
```

**Note** : The `UTF-8` encoding can handle any Unicode character. It is also backwards
compatible with `ASCII`, so that a pure `ASCII` file can also be considered a `UTF-8`
file, and a `UTF-8` file that happens to use only `ASCII` characters is identical to an
`ASCII` file with the same characters

Comment: Right, but not every `latin-1` string is not a valid `utf-8` string.